# React useState renders initial value even when state is updated

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am having trouble with useState updating state onSubmit.

This is a simple weather app to learn React Hooks.  I have read Dan Abramov's blog post several times on how to use useEffect.  I have tried finding something close to my problem on Stackoverflow but it isn't clicking.

```
   const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
   // Query term
   const [query, setQuery] = useState('indianapolis')
   // API search results
   const [data, setData] = useState([])


   useEffect(() => {
    let didCancel = false

    const getWeather = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}? 
        q=${query}&APPID=${apiKey}`)
        const data = await response.json()

        if (!didCancel) {
          setData(data)
        }
      } catch (error) {
        if (!didCancel) {
          throw new Error()
        }
      }
    }

    getWeather()

    return () => {
      // useEffect cleanup function
      didCancel = true
    }
  }, [query])

  const getSearchResults = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setQuery(search)
    props.history.push('/weather', [data])
    setSearch('')
  }
```

I expect the getSearchResults() function to update the setQuery function with the search term.  I used a console.log and found that my state was one step behind.  When I search, the first returned value is my initial value of query.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything particularly wrong, where do you check your `data`?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but what do mean by checking my `data`?  I have logged the data array and it sends the right information.

Comment: This sandbox illustrates the same problem https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-sun-yzjf1 Read this for the list of possible solutions https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#performance-optimizations